# How do I update multiple documents simultaneously filtered with different conditions at once through the MongoDB aggregation pipline or other queries?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongodb-atlas

Let's say

```
  const post = mongoose.model('post', { title: String, description: String, category: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'subcat' }] });
  const category = mongoose.model('category', { title: String, description: String });
  const subcat = mongoose.model('subcat', { title: String, description: String, category: [{ type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'category' }] });
  await category.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    $set: {
      is_deleted: true,
      deleted_at: new Date(),
    },
  });

  await subcat.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        category: { $in: [id] },
      },

      //  ......update on other documents as well i.e post
    },
  ]);
```

When a category is deleted, how do I update other documents (like posts and subcategories) that are related to the category simultaneously?
Suppose if I delete a category document, I want to delete subcategory documents that have only one item in the category array, which is the same category document. If the subcategory document has multiple categories and if any of the items match categoryId, I want to pull only that item from the array because it still has a category left that refers to the valid other category.

I have tried aggregation and update many queries in mongodb but couldn't come to any conclusion.

I want to make the above process in the same so that if the query does not succeed it doesn't effects all and vice versa.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a multi-document [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/) to me